# Java mouselistener

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

How do I go about writing a mouse listener that will react to pressing on any object in a `JFrame`, or on one particular object?

Here's my mouse listener -

```
class mouse extends MouseAdapter
{
   public void  mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
   {
     yearLabel.setText("nu");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can add a global mouse listener by ***[Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener,mask)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29)***

here is a example

```
public class SwingTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(new JButton("button"));
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
        mainPanel.add(label);

        showFrame("", mainPanel);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
                    MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent)event;
                    if(evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED){
                        label.setText("mouse clicked at: " + evt.getPoint());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public static JFrame showFrame(String title, Component component) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(900, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice example +1, btw `frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);` is useless in case if you want to put only one `JComponent` just frame.add(component); placed with BorderLayout.CENTER, if there are two or more then used LayoutManager is FlowLayout

Answer (score 2):

Did you attach this listener to the component containing `yearLabel`?  Additionally, I should comment that class names are by convention capitalized. Otherwise, you will confuse other programmers.